# How to transitions between scenes using SpriteView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, transition, skscene, spriteview

I have two scenes I want to transition between:

```
class TestGameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        size = view.frame.size
        scaleMode = .resizeFill
        let textNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Game Scene")
        textNode.position.x = size.width / 2
        textNode.position.y = size.height / 2
        addChild(textNode)
    }
}
```

to

```swift
class TestGameOverScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        size = view.frame.size
        scaleMode = .resizeFill
        backgroundColor = .red
        let textNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Game Over")
        textNode.position.x = size.width / 2
        textNode.position.y = size.height / 2
        addChild(textNode)
    }
}
```

I am currently presenting `TestGameScene` via a `SpriteView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: TestGameScene())
    }
}
```

In order to transition to the Game Over scene, I overrided `touchesBegan(_:with:)` in `TestGameScene` to present the Game Over scene like so:

```swift
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    view!.presentScene(TestGameOverScene(), transition: .fade(withDuration: 1.0))
}
```

Although this works, the `TestGameOverScene` gets deinitialised if the app goes into the background, which causes the Game Over scene to disappear. Is there a way to prevent this from happening or a better way to transition between two scenes when using SpriteView? I would like to use the fancy transitions provided by SpriteKit eg. `.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 0.5)` etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with a few ideas I came up with solution that works, however, I would love some criticism / analysis of how good this method is as I don't know much about memory management.

This class provides `ContentView` with the scene to render using `SpriteView`. It's a published property as when it changes, SwiftUI should be notified.

```swift
final class SceneProvider: ObservableObject { 
    @Published var scene: SKScene

    init() { 
        let initialScene = TestGameScene()
        self.scene = initialScene
        initialScene.viewState = self
    }
}
```

Added a binding/reference to the scene being presented by SwiftUI. We'll update this reference to the newly presented scene to notify SwiftUI.

```swift
class TestGameScene: SKScene { 
    unowned var viewState: SceneProvider!
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let sceneToPresent = TestGameOverScene()
        viewState.scene = sceneToPresent  // << we do this so SwiftUI updates
        view!.presentScene(sceneToPresent, transition: .fade(withDuration: 1.0))
    }
    // .. Rest is the same
}
```

From here, I could perhaps create a custom `SKScene` subclass that encapsulates all of this behaviour.

And of course,

```swift
struct ContentView: View { 
    @StateObject var sceneProvider = SceneProvider()  // << @StateObject ensures the container for the presented scene, ie. SceneProvider, isn't deallocated
    
    var body: some View { 
        SpriteView(scene: sceneProvider.scene)
    }
}
```

Using this method, `TestGameScene` gets deinitialised when the `TestGameOverScene` is presented - which is good (I think). In addition to this, SwiftUI maintains the newly presented scene even if you go to the background and come back as the `@Published` property along with `@StateObject` keeps SwiftUI up to date.

As there is only one scene held by `SceneProvider`, we don't have multiple scenes just taking up space in memory - which is good again (this I know is good for sure).

Would love some feedback on this.